# Pcie 1.1 device is not detected on a pcie gen 3 slot

Tags: linux, hardware, pci

My PC is running in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with kernel version 3.11.0-23.

The link below is my PC model:
http://www.villman.com/Product-Detail/HP_Pavilion_500_232d

I inserted a x4 pcie 1.1 device on the x16 PCIE 3.0 slot.
When I do lspci, my device is not shown in the list.

I tested my device on other PC with Gen 2.0 slot and it is detected.

Is there a way for my device to be detected?